# Set function return type in Haxe

Tags: haxe

For some reason, I get this error message whenever I try to compile this simple function: `Test.hx:1: lines 1-7 : Invalid -main : Test has invalid main function`

```
public static function main(a:Int, b:Int){
    trace("Calling main function");
    return a+b;
}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. What's wrong with this function definition, and how can I get it to compile correctly? I tried reading [the documentation](http://haxe.org/ref/syntax), and found it to be unclear in its explanation of how to properly set function return types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The special main entry function must be a `Void->Void` function. i.e. No param and no return value is allowed. Remember there is no command line argument concept in JS/Flash, which Haxe also compiles to. So we have to use system targets' API for that:

- `Sys.args() : Array<String>` to get the command line params.
- `Sys.exit( code : Int ) : Void` to exit with exit code.

FYI, the doc of `Sys` is at http://haxe.org/api/sys

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati flashvars is different from command line arguments. But of course, you can do the mapping between the two manually. Use `stage.loaderInfo.parameters[key]` to access flashvars.

Comment: Is it possible to set the return type of a function in Haxe, if it isn't the main method?  I tried defining a function as `static int function printSomething(thingToPrint){`, but it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @AndersonGreen The return type should be declared after the bracket: `static function printSomething(thingToPrint):Int { /*...*/ }`